# SSRS cannot map the input column, to the lookup column because the data types do not match but both are int

Tags: reporting-services, ssis

Why do I get the following error when both are int(eger) columns in a Lookup Transformation?

"Cannot map the input column 'ID', to the lookup column 'ID', because the data types do not match"

Comment: Could you check to see if the 'ID' column of input is INTEGER at the source Data Flow Component as well? This kind of case comes in when a refresh happens at the database end and is not changed at the Data Flow Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different integers in SSIS. SSIS has to match multiple data sources and destinations so your 'Integer' is quite a broad term here. You need to check the metadata of columns that you are matching and ensure that the datatypes are the same. For example, a standard, 32-bit signed integer is displayed in SSIS as DT_I4 but bigint is DT_I8.

Comment: I already solved my problem by adding a transformation step and you are bang on the money, both systems were different (2005 vs 2012 sql server versions) although both were int, so I don't get it but it's fixed with the transformation so I am not going to worry about it now.